# REST Endpoint for frequent sites activity

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, homepage

I would like to get frequent site activities like it is done in sharpoint.aspx.

[image: frequent sites screenshot]

Is there any endpoint which I can use to get those activities? (You viewed..., Something is popular etc.)

I have tried to use /_api/web/GetChanges but there are created, updated, deleted, renamed activities only.

Is there any endpoint to get it?